# Custom Icons in Plotly. Js the color and size

Tags: javascript, plotly

The Icons in Plotly Mode bar is Large, How could i change the size? I tried to add

```
a.modebar-btn {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

to CSS but it doesn't Work any Idea?